# Подсветка синтаксиса в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Как в редакторе Pycharm изменить цвет подсветки констант для Python, включая импортированные? В коде ниже редактор отображает AF_INET и CONSTANT белыми.

```py
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
CONSTANT = 'constant'
```

Comment: В Python нет констант. Даже если написать в верхнем регистре - это будет обычная переменная. Поэтому PyCharm и не различает их.

Comment: Если имя переменной/свойства и так капсом написано, зачем еще цветом выделять?

Comment: @insolor, хотелось при взгляде на вызов socket сразу видеть переменные. Ну да ладно, и правда капсом ведь написано, не стоит в радугу код превращать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно штатными средствами в настоящий момент. Соответствующий тикет в багтрекере https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26706

"Constant" в "Language Defaults" на Python не оказывает влияния.